# Changing the background colour of cells with particular word in it

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, datatable

I have a big datatable and i would like to mark all cells with "destroyed" in them red. I managed to do it using the following code but it takes ages and the file i want to use it on is even bigger. The word "destroyed" just appears in one column so can i just search in one column or is there another way to make it faster? I just created a table which has a similar size to my file as an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(21000, 4), columns=list('FCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = "destroyed"
df.iloc[1, 2] = "destroyed"
df.iloc[2, 2] = "running"
df.iloc[3, 2] = "destroyed"
df.iloc[4, 2] = "destroyed"
df.iloc[5, 2] = "running"
df.iloc[6, 2] = "destroyed"
df.iloc[7, 2] = "running"
df.iloc[8, 2] = "Verschrottet"
df.iloc[9, 2] = "running"
```

Creating the example Table.

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val == "destroyed" else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)

dat = "C:\User"
os.chdir(dat)
name = ('%s_Datenbank.xlsx' %("today"))

s.to_excel(name)
```

Creating the excel file with marked cells.
It should look like that afterwards.[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DttyK.png)